# Firefox: plain websocket working only on localhost

Tags: firefox, websocket, tornado

Recently, I have tried to get websockets working with Tornado as a server and plain websocket interface on browser.
I used [this](http://www.codestance.com/tutorials-archive/python-tornado-web-server-with-websockets-part-i-441) tutorial as starting point.
It works great in all browsers as it is. When I wanted to try it on my local network I have changed:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/?Id="+uid);
```

to:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://my.lan.ip.address:8888/?Id="+uid);
```

And it is working fine in Chrome, IE, Opera both on my PC and on other computers in network.
But it stops working on FireFox on my PC as well as on other computers.

I can see on serwer that it connects sucessfully, I can see response header in FF console, it triggers onopen event, but this line:

```
ws.send("Message to send");
```

has no result at all. It does not generate any message in console (neither error nor request), nothing is sended to serwer.

After a while I get "websocket the connection to was interrupted while the page was loading" error.

I removed any proxies in my FF settings, readed whole bunch of similar looking questions on SO and in other places, but to no result.

I am quite stuck here - I wloud be gratefull for any help. :)

The code for testing can be taken from this turorial I linked above. And issue is only in Firefox.